# updating more than one row at the time with select returning multiple ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I want to update a table based on the following query in `PostgreSQL`

```
UPDATE tableX
SET columnX = 100
WHERE id = (SELECT ID FROM tableY WHERE col1 = 'Y' AND col2 = 'Z');
```

And the problem is:

> Select query can return more than one row

. How do I update the table with only one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IN` instead of `=`:

```
update tableX
set columnX = 100
where id IN (select id from tableY where col1 = 'Y' and col2 = 'Z');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check that the id is in the list returned.

```
update tableX
set columnX = 100
where id in (select id from tableY where col1 = 'Y' and col2 = 'Z');
```

Answer (score 2):

And for completeness:

You need not use a subquery in the first place. You could also use:

```
update tableX
set columnX = 100
from tableY
where tableX.id=tableY.id
and tableY.col1 = 'Y'
and tableY.col2 = 'Z';
```